# Binomial GLM Feature Selection with rfe function in caret

Tags: r, glm

Is it possible to use the rfe function in the caret package to do feature selection on a binomial GLM? I would like to pass the data frame of predictors and predictions and have it return the best model and features. If not is there another package I should use?

Answer (score 1):

See `?lrFuncs` for what you desire, although you are probably better off using regularization via `glmnet` than a feature selection wrapper method.

Max

Comment: lrFuncs is new in the latest version of the caret package. Unfortunately they added that late so I ended up writing my own set of functions which has the same `fit`. I also wrote my summary function which I really like. It has all the model evaluation functions I use which work very well for me. Many are not in the proverbial text books but work very well for me.

Comment: @topepo can you tell me why is better to use regularization? So the SA, GA and RFE algorithms in caret should not be used with logistic regression?